# How to install hplip 3.17.11 under Ubuntu 17.10 for HP OfficeJet Pro 8720

Tags: hp

I'm using `Ubuntu 17.10`

According to the release notes https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/release_notes I need hplip 3.17.11.

I've tried installing from the shell installer with the following:

```
error: Configure failed with error: libnetsnmp not found
```

When I do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libsnmp-dev
```

I get

```
libsnmp-dev is already the newest version (5.7.3+dfsg-1.7ubuntu1)
```

And apt is an older version

```
apt-cache policy hplip
hplip:
  Installed: 3.17.7+repack0-3
  Candidate: 3.17.7+repack0-3
  Version table:
 *** 3.17.7+repack0-3 500
      500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
      100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can install and/or debug this?

Output of

```
dpkg -S libnetsnmp
libsnmp-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmphelpers.a
libsnmp30:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmphelpers.so.30
libsnmp30:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpagent.so.30
libsnmp-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpagent.a
libsnmp-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmptrapd.so
libsnmp30:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpmibs.so.30.0.3
libsnmp-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpagent.so
libsnmp30:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpmibs.so.30
libsnmp-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmp.a
libsnmp-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmp.so
libsnmp30:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmptrapd.so.30.0.3
libsnmp-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpmibs.a
libsnmp-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmphelpers.so
libsnmp30:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpagent.so.30.0.3
libsnmp30:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmp.so.30
libsnmp30:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmphelpers.so.30.0.3
libsnmp-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpmibs.so
libsnmp30:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmptrapd.so.30
libsnmp-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmptrapd.a  
libsnmp30:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmp.so.30.0.3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software.  Since you ask why a given version is 'so old'.  Installing from source is its own problem, and you don't give enough details to solve that problem, so the question is also possibly "unclear"

Comment: I just updated the question

Comment: If you would examine [hplip news and anouncments](https://launchpad.net/hplip/+announcements). They follow a simple release naming schema of major_number.yy.mm. So release 3.17.7 is only about 5 months old, with the newest release being one month old.

Comment: I've seen several similar threads https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/63843 and I haven't been able to resolve it. Not sure why I'm down voted when I'm having a legitimate problem.  And the release notes of HPLIP 3.17.11 clearly say Ubuntu 17.10. So I would like to install HPLIP 3.17.11

Comment: libsnmp30 is already the newest version (5.7.3+dfsg-1.7ubuntu1).

Comment: This reads like a classic XY Problem. Taking a step back, why do you need to install this particular driver? Are you having an issue with the installation of a particular HP printer?

Comment: Yes I want to print to my wireless HP printer.

Comment: @eflanigan00, please edit your question to include the name and model of the HP printer that you're having issues with so we can better troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: Updated the printer name in the title. I think I just need the hp driver. Next time I will not upgrade my ubuntu so fast...

Comment: Per your link to [hp release notes](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/release_notes) your printer was supported in HPLIP 3.16.5. Could you clarify that you have or have not been able to use the 8720 with `hplip 3.17.7`. 3.17.7 is available in the official repos, so no special effort should be needed.

Comment: Per the hp release  notes HPLIP 3.17.11 "Added support for the following new Distros: - Ubuntu 17.10 (64bit)" This explains why it worked before the upgrade and not after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded distributions

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Now I get this output:

```
apt-cache policy hplip
hplip:
  Installed: 3.17.10+repack0-2
  Candidate: 3.17.10+repack0-2
  Version table:
 *** 3.17.10+repack0-2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I am able to print again.

Comment: I have no idea but emk2203 might be correct. Upgrading distributions might have cleared whatever was in conflict before.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that `hplip` 3.17.11 added support for Ubuntu 17.10 is not relevant to your problem here. You don't want to look at which distribution is supported natively by HP, you want to see from which version on your printer is supported. `hplip` is supplied by Ubuntu for quite some time, you don't need to have it supplied by HP.

`hplip` is part of Ubuntu 17.10 in version 3.17.7. You can install it without problems with just `apt install hplip`.

Now what version do you need? From the [release notes](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/release_notes) you quoted, it is apparent that your printer HP Officejet Pro 8720 is supported since `hplip` 3.16.5, so you would be fine with the distribution-supplied version.

To rescue your installation, roll back and uninstall what you have installed for the shell installer. Afterwards, do a `apt install hplip` as mentioned above.

That should do the job.

Comment: As I stated above I get

libsnmp-dev is already the newest version (5.7.3+dfsg-1.7ubuntu1), printer isn't working.

Comment: Wow I can't believe you got my bounty for an answer that doesn't even work. Meanwhile I'm being down voted...

Comment: The error is the following (distro not supported) File "/usr/share/hplip/installer/core_install.py", line 475, in init
    self.distro_name = self.distros_index[self.distro]

Comment: You don't need to install *ANY* dev package for the Ubuntu-supplied `hplip` to work. The answer doesn't work because you borked your system with the shell install. Purge the installed dev packages for `hplip`, delete everything manually installed for it. Try to start as clean as possible.

Comment: I think I did that already. I will try again this weekend. Unless a patch was applied to the ubuntu hplip it will not work  on ubunut 17.10 unless I use hplip 3.17.11. There is an explicit check in the code looking for the correct os.

Comment: Be very thorough with the cleanup. Trust me, I have been there before, and I know these symptoms. Trying to install from source systemwide is a recipe for disaster if it goes wrong, and you need to find every mismatched lib which got installed.

If you examine the ubuntu `hplip`, you'll see that the name contains the ubuntu string. You can look up the differences and patches to the original on launchpad. But be assured, the package from the repos work  together if they support your printer.

Comment: Thanks emk! You should post this as a proposed solution. I will accept it if it works.

Comment: I removed everything I possibly could. And reinstalled hplip. Still not working.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hplip/+bug/1744587

Comment: Do the following: Make a clean install of Ubuntu 17.10. Install `hplip` from the Ubuntu repos. Install printer. This WILL work. Your system is still tainted in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the HP ubuntu driverq directly from [HP website here:](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing)

using `sudo ./hplip*.run`

but got

### RE-CHECKING DEPENDENCIES

error: A required dependency 'pyqt5-dbus (PyQt 5 DBus - DBus Support for PyQt5)' is still missing.
error: A required dependency 'pyqt5 (PyQt 5- Qt interface for Python (for Qt version 4.x))' is still missing.
error: Installation cannot continue without these dependencies.
error: Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.

Then installed [using pip](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html) (verify the python version being used):

```
pip3 install pyqt5
pip3 install pyqt5-bus
```

rerun the installer and then it worked successfully.